# Is there a window manager for Windows 7 that will allow me to assign a hotkey to a specific window?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I'm looking for a Windows 7 window manager that will allow me to assign a hotkey, such as `<Win>-<F-n>` to bring the focus to a specific window. Sometimes `Alt-<Tab>`just isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first ten can be accessed with Win+1, 2...9, 0
Is that not sufficient?

Comment: It is now that I know about it.

Comment: I had a feeling : )